# How to refresh tkinter entry value? I get a 1-click lag

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I built an interface where the user fills a hierarchical form. Past values are displayed in a `ttk.Treeview`.
I allow the user to edit previous values by clicking on the tree. The value gets filled on the form where it can be edited and overwriten.

The problem: the value I insert on the `Entry` widget is only displayed the next time the user clicks it, so that it is always 1 click lagging. Please run my sample code to get a better understanding. It gets confusing because if the user clicks a value and then another, it will display the previously clicked value.

It must have something to do with the event handling routine in tkinter, but I could not find and answer.
How can I get rid of this lag?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()

def cb_clique(event):
    item = tree.selection()[0]
    entry1.delete(0, "end")
    entry1.insert(0, item)

entry1 = tk.Entry(root, width=15)
entry1.grid(row=1,column=1)

tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.bind("<Button-1>", cb_clique)
tree["columns"]=("valor")
tree.column("valor", width=200 )
tree.heading("valor", text="Valor")
tree.grid(row=3, column = 1, columnspan = 4)
tree.insert("", "end", iid = "Will display position",text = "Click me",
           values=("a","b"))
tree.insert("", "end", iid = "Use position to get info",
           text = "Click me", values=("a","b"))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `<Button-1>` event triggers before the window notices that the selection has changed, so `selection()` returns the thing that was selected before your click. Try changing the event binding to `<<TreeViewSelect>>`.

```
tree.bind("<<TreeviewSelect>>", cb_clique)
```

Comment: Thank you! I had been looking for a fix for quite some time! Now it is great! And it indeed does not lag if I simply set a value to the entry that does not require the selection, but I had failed to notice that, so I was trying to solve the wrong problem.